# VB.NET - Encrypt a string using RSA Public Key file

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I need to encrypt a string like "1111111111" using a public key file (generated using RSA) as this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXo
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXrD0/SN6QTZMhEcDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

My difficulty is obtain an **RSAParameters** object starting from the public key file.

I read many questions about this topic but I'm new in cryptography.

Can you provide me an example?

Tell me if you need additional information!

Comment: is your question about generating the Pub/Priv key or about using them to encrypt/decrypt?

Comment: Not an expert on RSA encryption, but check these links: [Public Key RSA Encryption in C# .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10877/Public-Key-RSA-Encryption-in-C-NET) and [RSA Private Key Encryption](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38739/RSA-Private-Key-Encryption.)

Comment: @Plutonix I need to using them to encrypt.

Comment: Also check MSDN: [RSACryptoServiceProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) - there is an example at the bottom of the page.